# Avoid unnecessary Jetpack compose recomposition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition, android-compose

So I have this structure.

```
sealed class ViewState {
    object Loading : ViewState()

    data class Content(
        val toolbarUiModel: MyToolbarUiModel? = null,
        val listUiModel : ListUiModel? = null,
        ...
    ) : ViewState()
}
```

And in activity

```
val uiState: ViewState by viewModel.viewState.collectAsState()

when (uiState) {
  is Content -> {
    Content(
       uiState
    )
  }

  is EmptyState -> ...
}
```

And Content looks like this :

```
Content(
   val state : ViewState
) {
  ...
  state.listUiModel?.let { uiModel ->
    MyListComponent()
  }
  ...
}
```

Now what happens is even if I make changes only in `ListUiModel` or any single Ui Model, the  entire Content composable is getting recomposed, because in ViewModel, I am doing

```
fun updateListUiMode() {
   _state = _state.copy(listUiModel = newModel) // This triggers recomposition of the entire screen. However, only ListComponent is expected to be recomposed.
}
```

Is my code structure wrong? Because I don’t want to recompose entire screen when I update only a single component. Am I missing anything?

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: You have passed the ```state``` as a parameter in Content Composable to it will Recompose Entire Content

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try passing individual UI models to Content composable but still I am getting same result. I'll try one more time though

Comment: @Kaustubh you best approach would be having individual states for every single thing then that would mean you recompose only the necessary composables